# Imput a number with keyboard in Appium test

Tags: appium, android-softkeyboard, appium-android

I am trying to test my application with Appium and when I insert a text in a box (in this case it would be a phone number) I get my test to be valid but at no time do I see the text in the box with Android studio.
This is the code I am using.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText"))
        .click();

    boolean isKeyboardShown = driver.isKeyboardShown();
        
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@text=\"+34 \"]")).sendKeys("5");
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the UI and the XML layout of the screen as observed with Appium Inspector Tool or UiAutomator Tool or Appium Desktop?